# set all steps within a day to missing if any hourly step is missing in a netcdf

Tags: python, netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have a netcdf file with an hourly timestep, and with some values missing.  What I want to do is, for each gridcell, set all hourly step to missing if any hourly step of that particular day is missing.  Preferably in `cdo` or `nco` if possible.

I came up with the following `cdo` based solution, which makes a mask using a `gec` logical and then using the `dayavg` command to get a daily mask of 1 if all timesteps are okay, or miss if any of them are missing. I can then use `mul` to wipe all hourly slices where any values are missing, like this:

```
# low threshold in gec to ensure output is 1 for any data value
cdo dayavg -gec,-1e32 in.nc mask.nc # use avg NOT mean
cdo mul in.nc mask.nc out.nc
```

This works, but:

- It only works for a single day of data (there is not yet a `daymul` function in cdo, pity) so you need to extract data one day at a time in a loop, extremely slow and clunky
- it feels like a big fudge using the `gec` logical with some very low threshold

so I wondering if I'm missing a neater solution in `cdo` or a more concise way of doing this in `nco`?

EDIT 01/2021:  I thought there was a `daymul` function in cdo so at least I could use the above method on multi-day timeseries, but surprisingly there wasn't.  However, Uwe very kindly responded to my request to add `daymul` and `daydiv` functions into cdo, which will be available from version v2.0.3 in January 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this is as concise as you will get in CDO.

However, I find a less "fudgy" way of doing this is using the `eq` operator. This is generally a neater (and I think faster) way to create a mask file where 1 is non-NA and NA is missing. So your second line becomes:

```
cdo dayavg -eq in.nc in.nc mask.nc
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Can I ask, is this function safe with a floating point field? I always worry using eq on floats in case it fails due to some kind of rounding issue

Comment: It's never caused me problems, but potentially it's not 100% robust with all data types.

Comment: I suppose comparing a field with itself should be the most safe usage of eq on floats, if that weren't bit reproducible it would be concerning...